# How to add string at the end of cycle

Tags: javascript

I have the array and need to divide 3 student per 3 array. Need to get the following results per cases:

1. `sortStudentsByGroups(students)`  =>

   ```
   [  [ 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Bernard' ],  [ 'Cris', 'Josh', 'Mark' ],  [ 'Peter', 'Sam', 'Sandra' ],  'Rest students: Takesi']
   ```
2. if to delete one student from the list, will get:

   ```
   [
     [ 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Bernard' ],
     [ 'Cris', 'Josh', 'Mark' ],
     [ 'Peter', 'Sam', 'Sandra' ],
     'Rest students: -'
   ]
   ```

My CODE:

```
const students = [
  "Peter",
  "Andrew",
  "Ann",
  "Mark",
  "Josh",
  "Sandra",
  "Cris",
  "Bernard",
  "Takesi",
  "Sandra",
];

function sortStudentsByGroups(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  const arrNew = [];
  const arr_size = 3;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += arr_size) {
    let y = arr.slice(i, i + arr_size);

    arrNew.push(y);

    if (y.length < 3) {
      let u = y.join(", ");
      arrNew.push(`Rest students: ${u}`);
    }
  }

  console.log(arrNew);
}

sortStudentsByGroups(students);
```

For 1 option I have correct result:

```
[
  [ 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Bernard' ],
  [ 'Cris', 'Josh', 'Mark' ],
  [ 'Peter', 'Sandra', 'Sandra' ],
  [ 'Takesi' ],
  'Rest students: Takesi'
]
```

And don't know how to get result for 2-nd option, exactly add to arr 'Rest students: -'

```
[
  [ 'Andrew', 'Ann', 'Bernard' ],
  [ 'Cris', 'Josh', 'Mark' ],
  [ 'Peter', 'Sam', 'Sandra' ],
  'Rest students: -'
]
```

I tried to push in array and as the result iterating every time

Comment: FWIW I would strongly recommend against having your array be heterogeneous like that: consider that the code processing this result iterates over the sub-arrays with a `for` loop the way you're doing to the original array. Strings have a length, and you can iterate over the individual characters with a `for` loop just like you can the elements of an array. I can pretty much guarantee if you write your code this way 6 months from now you're going to get a bug report and start debugging and see `'R', 'e', 's', 't'...`. Be kind to the person who has to maintain your code. Especially if it's you.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm just get practice for my own. But you advice will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to distribute normally, then pick the last element and check its size:

```js
function sortStudentsByGroups(arr, size) {
    const arrNew = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) 
        arrNew.push(arr.slice(i, i + size))
    
    let last = arrNew.pop()

    if (last.length < size)
        arrNew.push('Rest: ' + last.join())
    else
        arrNew.push(last, 'Rest: -')

    return arrNew
}

console.log(...sortStudentsByGroups('A B C D E F'.split(' '), 3))
console.log(...sortStudentsByGroups('A B C D E F G'.split(' '), 3))
console.log(...sortStudentsByGroups('A B C D E F G H'.split(' '), 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have handled the case, when you have "y" value <3 i.e, if y is 3, then you have appended right? so if the no. of people are multiple of 3 only, your 2nd test case fails.

so, you can add else condition here,

```js
const students = [
  "Peter",
  "Andrew",
  "Ann",
  "Mark",
  "Josh",
  "Sandra",
  "Cris",
  "Bernard",
  "Takesi",
  "Sandra",
];

function sortStudentsByGroups(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  const arrNew = [];
  const arr_size = 3;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += arr_size) {
    let y = arr.slice(i, i + arr_size);

    arrNew.push(y);

    if (y.length < 3) {
      let u = y.join(", ");
      arrNew.push(`Rest students: ${u}`);
    }
    if (i+arr_size >= arr.length){
    arrNew.push("Rest students: -");
    }
    

  }

  console.log(arrNew);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your rest students logic outside the loop and use

```
arr.slice(-arr.length % arr_size || arr.length)
```

to get the remaining students and join them with `,` .
If the string is empty that means no students left, so add `|| '-'` to display the dash.

Btw you mutate the original array with `sort()`. If that's not desired, just copy the array: `arr = arr.slice().sort()`.

```js
const students = [
  "Peter",
  "Andrew",
  "Ann",
  "Mark",
  "Josh",
  "Sandra",
  "Cris",
  "Bernard",
  "Takesi",
  "Sandra",
];

const students2 = [
  "Peter",
  "Andrew",
  "Ann",
  "Mark",
  "Josh",
  "Sandra",
  "Cris",
  "Bernard",
  "Sandra",
];

function sortStudentsByGroups(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  const arrNew = [];
  const arr_size = 3;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += arr_size) {
    let y = arr.slice(i, i + arr_size);
    arrNew.push(y);
  }
  
  arrNew.push(`Rest students: ${arr.slice(-arr.length % arr_size || arr.length).join(', ') || '-'}`);

  return arrNew;
}

sortStudentsByGroups(students).map(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));
sortStudentsByGroups(students2).map(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do your function like that:

```
function sortStudentsByGroups(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  const arrNew = [];
  const arr_size = 3;

  let remainingStudents = [...arr];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += arr_size) {
    let y = remainingStudents.slice(0, arr_size);

    arrNew.push(y);

    if (y.length < 3) {
      let u = y.join(", ");
      arrNew.push(`Rest students: -`);
    }

    remainingStudents = remainingStudents.slice(arr_size);
  }

  console.log(arrNew);
}
```

Comment: Good answers on Stack Overflow are more than just providing code that works. Good answers should explain what the problem was and how  your code solves it. Where appropriate, links to documentation are also good to add.